# Oracle SQL regexp date formatting

Tags: regex, oracle

im so new in oracle, and trying to select some bad formatted date as cleaned.
for example,
my field is: `12.05.2010 dfsafs()F(Gf, 12:45`
can i select it as `12.05.2010 12:45` with regexp or something else ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex to match date and time formats.

```
[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wX5eU3/1)

In oracle, i think you need to escape the curly braces.

```
[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{4\}|[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}
```

Comment: oracle's regexp_replace function doesnt allow to use global 'g'

Comment: then don't use that. Some prog languages has `g` flag enabled by default . Ex, php

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should works:

```
select regexp_substr(dat,'.*(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}).*',1,1,'i',1) ||' '||
regexp_substr(dat,'.*(\d{2}:\d{2}).*',1,1,'i',1) datetime
from 
(select '12.05.2010 dfsafs()F(Gf, 12:45' dat from dual);
```

Check that i extract date and time using `regexp_substr` and then concat both values.